# Ajuda com lógica de Checkin e Checkout

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de credenciamento com *checkin* e *checkout*. Está tudo funcionando, porém somente não consigo fazer o seguinte:
Quando faço o *checkin*, ele cadastra; quando faço novamente, ele cadastro de novo. Preciso que ele barre esse cadastro dizendo que já está "dentro da feira"; só quando passar pelo *checkout* ele poderá entrar novamente.

```
<?php
require_once('../controller/checkinsController.php');
salvarCheckin();
?>

<?php
require_once ('../config.php');
require_once ("../inc/visibilidade-header.php");
?>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#campoCPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
    });
</script>
<?php if ($_REQUEST['posicao']=='checkin'):
        $posicao = '1';         
?>
<h2>Check-in</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($_REQUEST['posicao']=='checkout'):
        $posicao = '0';         
?>
<h2>Check-out</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<form id="formCheckin" action="add.php?posicao_atual=<?php echo $posicao; ?>" method="post">
    <!-- area de campos do form -->
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="name">CODIGO DE BARRA</label>
            <input type="text" name="codigo_barra" onfocus="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" maxlength="10" onchange="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}"  onkeyup="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" onblur="if(this.value.length==10){submeter()}" id="codigo_barra" />

        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Estou aqui!</button>
            <a href="../index.php" class="btn btn-default">Voltar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<?php include(FOOTER_TEMPLATE); ?>
```

Esse é meu `Controller`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: andre.luis.a.costa
 * Date: 03/12/2016
 * Time: 16:07
 */

require_once('../config.php');
require_once(DBAPI);

$checkin = null;

/**
 *
 */
function salvarCheckin() {


    $db = open_database();

    if (!empty($_POST['codigo_barra'])) {
        $posicao =  $_REQUEST['posicao_atual'];

        $today = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Recife'));

        $checkin["codigo_barra"] = $_POST['codigo_barra'];
        $checkin["posicao"] = $posicao;
        $checkin['created'] = $today->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $checkin['modified'] = $checkin['created'];

         $retorno = ultimaPosicaoVisitante($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db, $posicao);

        $retorno = validarCadastroCodigoVisitante($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db);

        if($retorno){
            save('checkins', $checkin);
            echo "<script>alert(".json_encode($_SESSION['message']).")</script>";
        } else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Visitante não cadastrado! Favor realizar o cadastro!";
            echo "<script>alert(".json_encode($_SESSION['message']).")</script>";

        }

    } 
}

function validarCadastroCodigoVisitante($codigo_barra, $db) {
    $existeVisitante = false;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM visitantes WHERE codigo_barra = '$codigo_barra' ";

    $search = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        //mysqli_result['num_rows']
        // var_dump($search);
    if (isset($search)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($search,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    if(isset($row) > 0){
        $existeVisitante = true;
    }

    return $existeVisitante;

}
function ultimaPosicaoVisitante($codigo_barra, $db, $posicao) {
    $posicaoVisitante = false;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE codigo_barra = '$codigo_barra' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC  ";

    $search = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        //mysqli_result['num_rows']
        // var_dump($search);
    if (isset($search)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($search,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    if(isset($row['posicao']) == "$posicao"){
        $posicaoVisitante = true;
    }

    return $posicaoVisitante;

}

?>
```

Comment: Essa função ``save($checkin)`` está incluindo em um banco de dados ``checkin``, correto? O lance seria verificar, antes de salvar, se o ``codigo_barra`` já existe nessa tabela, não? Ou ele pode fazer checkin e checkout várias vezes?

Comment: Exatamente amigo @Daniel esta vindo de um DB, o codigo_barra esta vindo do DB tambem, eu nao estou conseguindo exatamente isso, que o mesmo codigo_barra Ex: 05552225 deu 'Checkin' --- se eu for passar esse novamente aparece a mensagem de erro, so liberando se for passar no 'CheckOut'

Comment: Essa linha: ``$retorno = validarCadastroCodigoVisitante($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db);
`` tá retornando true ou false, né? Você precisa fazer algo parecido, com o que fez em ``validarCadastroCodigoVisitante`` antes de salvar (ou dentro da função salvar). Faz um ``SELECT`` e vê se já tem alguém com esse código de barras no cadastro de checkins.

Comment: como exatamente, é ai qe ta o problema, não estou encontrando o modo para fazer isso, poderia ser mais claro, sou iniciante com isso :P @Daniel

Comment: Ué, você fez isso cara: você verificou se o código de barras já existe na tabela visitantes. É só fazer a mesma coisa na tabela de checkin. Seria alguma coisa tipo ``SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE codigo_barra = '$codigo_barra'`` e verifica se o retorno veio vazio: ``count($checkins)``.

Comment: Nada, eu criei o Select no SalvarChekin e não fez diferença! acho qe me embananei todo... porqe ele ta criando constantemente, ele nao ta parando nesse que ja foi criado! vc nao poderia me ajudar mostrando no codigo acima?? ajuda ai amigo! por favor!

Deixa eu ser mais claro!!!
isso que ta acontecendo!! 
um numero EX: 12345678 aperta o Checkin ele registra ai fica como 1, se novamente o 12345678 apertar no Checkin ele ta indo criando novamente com o 0 ao invez de travar a passagem dele!!!

nisso qe eu to me travado!

Comment: Fica como 1? Aonde? Cara, bota o código dessa função ``save()`` se não fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: esse comentario foi antes de vc mandar, estou testando aqi ja 1 mint qe ja te digo se funfou! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentando te ajudar aí, conforme pediu nos comentários, mas sinceramente estou tentando sacar qual a dificuldade.

```
function salvarCheckin() {


    $db = open_database();

    if (!empty($_POST['codigo_barra'])) {
        $posicao =  $_REQUEST['posicao_atual'];

        $today = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Recife'));

        $checkin["codigo_barra"] = $_POST['codigo_barra'];
        $checkin["posicao"] = $posicao;
        $checkin['created'] = $today->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $checkin['modified'] = $checkin['created'];

         $retorno = ultimaPosicaoVisitante($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db, $posicao);

        $retorno = validarCadastroCodigoVisitante($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db);

        if($retorno){
            if (verificarSeCheckinJaExiste($checkin['codigo_barra'], $db)) {
               $_SESSION['message'] = "Visitante já fez checkin!";
               echo "<script>alert(".json_encode($_SESSION['message']).")</script>";
               return false;
            }
            save('checkins', $checkin);
            echo "<script>alert(".json_encode($_SESSION['message']).")</script>";
        } else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Visitante não cadastrado! Favor realizar o cadastro!";
            echo "<script>alert(".json_encode($_SESSION['message']).")</script>";

        }

    } 
}

function verificarSeCheckinJaExiste($codigo_barra, $db) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE codigo_barra = '$codigo_barra'";
    $sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $sql);
    $search = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($search)
    if ($rows > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Como dá pra ver, tive que usar o mysqli_num_rows pra contar quantas linhas vieram no resultado, segue documentação: http://php.net/results.php?q=mysqli_num_rows&l=pt_BR&p=all

Comment: Vou testar aqi amigo...vc ta me ajudando pacas demais serio!